# Collapsing list to unique IDs with a range of dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large list of IDs that repeat with different ranges of dates. I need to create a unique list of IDs with just one range of dates that includes the earliest start date and latest end date from the uncollapsed list.

this is an example of what I have:

```
    id  start_date  end_date
    1   9/25/2015   10/12/2015
    1   9/16/2015   11/1/2015
    1   8/25/2015   9/21/2015
    2   9/2/2015    10/29/2015
    3   9/18/2015   10/15/2015
    3   9/19/2015   9/30/2015
    4   8/27/2015   9/15/2015
```

And this is what I need.

```
   id   start_date  end_date
   1    8/25/2015   11/1/2015
   2    9/2/2015    10/29/2015
   3    9/18/2015   10/15/2015
   4    8/27/2015   9/15/2015
```

I'm trying to get this in Python, but not having much luck. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`groupby/aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html):

```
In [12]: df.groupby('id').agg({'start_date':min, 'end_date':max})
Out[12]: 
   start_date   end_date
id                      
1  2015-08-25 2015-11-01
2  2015-09-02 2015-10-29
3  2015-09-18 2015-10-15
4  2015-08-27 2015-09-15
```

Note that it is important that `start_date` and `end_date` be parsed as dates, so that `min` and `max` return the minimum and maximum *date*s for each `id`. If the values are merely string representations of dates, then `min` and `max` would give the *string* min or max which depends on string lexicographic order. If the date-strings were in `YYYY/MM/DD` format, then lexicographic order would correspond to parsed-date order, but  date-strings in the `MM/DD/YYYY` format do not have this property.

If `start_date` and `end_date` have string values, then

```
for col in ['start_date', 'end_date']:
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col])
```

would convert the strings into dates.

If you are loading the DataFrame from a file using `pd.read_table` (or `pd.read_csv`), then

```
df = pd.read_table(filename, ..., parse_dates=[1, 2])
```

would parse the strings in the second and third columns of the file as dates. `[1, 2]` corresponds to the second and third columns since Python uses 0-based indexing.